# Append picked image using imagePicker into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {            
        selectedImageArray.append(pickedImage)            
    }        
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)        
}
```

I want get picked image into an selectedImageArray,but didn't get image doing this.

Comment: Do you enter the 'if-let' or is it not casting to UIImage?

Comment: Did you remember to add the object this function is in as the delegate of the picker?

Answer (score 0):

To get picked image you have to use **NSMutableArray**

Make one public array and add object in it.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    // assign pickup image into varibale
    var selectedimage : UIImage!
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedimage = editedImage
    }
    else
    {
        selectedimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    self.testArray.addObject(selectedimage)
}
```